# Fields with characteristic 0 are not finitely axiomatizable in FOPC

Tags: finite-fields, first-order-logic, predicate-logic, model-theory, axioms

It is easy to show that there exist finite sets of sentences $\phi_p$ such that for any $p$ prime, the models of $\phi_p$ are exactly the fields with characteristic $p$. It is also easy to show that there exists an infinite set of sentences $\phi_0$  such that the models of $\phi_0$ are exactly the fields with characteristic 0.

Does there exist a finite set of sentences such that its models are exactly the fields with characteristic $0$?

I tried arriving at a contradiction using various constructions and the Completeness Theorem, but it seems like it is necessary to make an explicit choice of $\phi_0$ in order to produce one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is not possible. Note that if there was such a finite set of sentences, then we could take their conjunction to get a single sentence characterizing fields of characteristic $0$, and taking its negation gives a formula $\psi$ characterizing fields of positive characteristic.

Since fields of arbitrary positive characteristic satisfy $\psi$, we get that the theory consisting of $\psi,2\neq 0,3\neq 0,5\neq 0,\dots,p\neq 0$ is consistent for all primes $p$. But then by compactness so is the theory consisting of $\psi$ and $p\neq 0$ for *all* primes $p$ at once. But a field satisfying all those statements must have characteristic $0$, contradicting our assumptions on $\psi$.